# Ingest a serialized object created in R into Python

Tags: python, r, serialization

I would like to ingest a serialized object created in R into Python.
An obvious solution is to write csv files from R, and then ingest the csv file into python. Unfortunately, the remote system does not have R interpreter.

I have tried to use both pickle and json without any lucks.
Any feedbacks would be greatly appreciated!

R code

```
x <- serialize(list(1,2,3), NULL, ascii=TRUE)
xzip <- memCompress(x,'bzip2')
to.write = file("./rbinfile.dat", "wb")
writeBin(xzip, to.write)
close(to.write)
```

Python code

```
import bz2
import binascii
with open("./rbinfile.dat","rb") as fObj:
    xzip = fObj.readline()
x = bz2.decompress(xzip)
x = binascii.hexlify(x)
```

How do I unserialize x to recover the original list?